# Deploy de una aplicación Spring Boot en un VPS unmanaged

Tags: java, spring, servidor, hosting, vps

Tengo un archivo .JAR el cual contiene mi aplicación Spring con todas sus dependencias. Contrate tambien un VPS el cual hoy el soporte me comenta que sus VPS son "*unmanaged*", o sea, no administrados (no se si esto imposibilita lo que quiero hacer).

El `DocumentRoot` el cual se encuentra en el directorio `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` apunta a `/var/www/html`. Aquí hay un archivo de extensión .html que es el archivo default que carga el navegador al hacer una petición al dominio que apunta a mi servidor.

Sin tener mucho conocimiento del tema he subido a ese directorio mi archivo .JAR y desde la linea de comandos con java -jar nombre_archivo.jar ejecuto mi aplicacion. 
Se levanta y se inicia sin problemas, pero al ingresar nuevamente a mi dominio me sale la tipica pagina con el titulo

"**Index of /**" y el listado de archivos que hay en esa carpeta.

Tengo todo instalado en el servidor, mysql, maven, java, etc.

¿Mi aplicación va en otro directorio o este tipo de aplicaciones no corren en servidores ***unmanaged***?

Comment: ¿Tu aplicación se levanta escuchando en el puerto 80 o en otro distinto? Cuando dices que te muestra "el listado de archivos que hay en esa carpeta", ¿te refieres a /var/www/html? Siendo una aplicación Spring Boot, no debes ponerla ahí, cópiala en cualquier directorio que no sea ese

Comment: Ah, me olvidaba. El que sea unmanaged significa que tú eres el responsable de la gestión del software que haya de ejecutarse en ese servidor. El proveedor simplemente te da un SO funcional y conectado a la red y se asegura de que tu máquina no se caiga, lo demás es cosa tuya (por tanto, lo primero que debes hacer es instalar y configurar un cortafuegos)

Comment: @IvanClavijos en mi pc se levantaba con el 8080... En el vsp no tengo ni idea la verdad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto, una aplicación Spring Boot se levanta escuchando en el puerto 8080, así que si no has configurado tu aplicación para que use otro, en el servidor usará el mismo.

Si quieres que tu aplicación en el servidor escuche en el 80, para el servidor Apache que ha tienes corriendo (y que es el que te sirve ese contenido que estás viendo) y arranca la app así:

```
java -jar tu_archivo.jar --server.port=80
```

Aún y así, arranca la app y prueba a acceder a tu domino:8080 para validar que llegas a ella

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error: The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Comment: De todos modos si ejecuto java -jar tu_archivo.jar (sin el puerto) y en navegador voy a midominio.com:8080 parece cargarla (me sale un error 500 porque aun no hice las tablas de la BD). Seria que asi funciona? Si es asi, ¿No hay forma de poder ejecutar mi app con "midominio.com" o no con "midominio.con:8080". Gracias de antemano !

Comment: Ese primer error es lógico. Fíjate que te decía que antes debías parar el servidor Apache, que es el que te está ocupando el 80 y por eso te da el primer error que has comentado. Como bien dices, si atacas el 8080 y te está dando ese error 500 es porque, efectivamente, estás accediendo a ella

Comment: ¿No hay forma de poder ejecutar mi app con "midominio.com" o no con "midominio.con:8080"?

Comment: Sí si haces lo que te digo. Para el servidor Apache y levanta tu app en el puerto 80. Entonces ya podrás acceder con tudominio.com